# javascript running dynamic code from a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is the html code
Test

I am a newbie and running this code in a js file and it works. Only problem is that is does all the buttons on my JQUERY Site.   Can anyone help me out and tell me how to make it specific to just one...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("js/jobs.json", function(result){
           $.each(result, function(i, field){
                $("div").append(field + " ");
                            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Which single button do you want it to apply to?

Comment: fix your selector: e.g. use an id for your button(say MyId) and change your selector to $('#MyId')

Comment: Using `ID`s will work, but I would advise against that, use either a data-attribute or class for targeting the buttons.  ID's pollute the global..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to add an id attribute to the specific button you want to target.  Then you will be able to add the click event like this:

```
$('#buttonId').click(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to learn HTML first. In this case you need to assign ID ATTRIBUTE to this element for example

```
<button id ='myButton'>Test</button>
```

After click on that button this code will work. But you need to target that exact button, see bellow

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myButton").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("js/jobs.json", function(result){
           $.each(result, function(i, field){
                $("div").append(field + " ");
                            });
        });
    });
});
```

You also did not post your HTML code which could be useful in writing this answer. Your JS code (JQ) will append this json results to ALL DIVS on your page becase of your selector (div).

Answer (score 0):

Always use a class as a selector.

Add a class to your HTML.

```
<button class='js-test-button'>Test</button>
```

and then you update JS code.

```
$(".js-test-button").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("js/jobs.json", function(result){
           $.each(result, function(i, field){
                $("div").append(field + " ");
                            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mybutton").click(function() {
        // your code comes here
        console.log("My button click");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="mybutton" value="Submit"/>
```